# Maven: building with submodules

Tags: java, maven

I need to create a zip from the main pom. The problem that when the creation is in the main one, it is launched before finishing the actions of the submodules.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.empresa.nombre.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
    </modules>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>finalName</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Module1 generates a war, module2 a .tar and module3 an ear.
All these files, war, tar and ear, are generated in the main target.

When building with
`mvn clean verify`
It shows the error of not finding anything, because it deletes everything in the target and tries to compress the folders that have not yet been created in the submodules.

`archive cannot be empty`

Is there a way to launch the submodules first and then launch the main pom build last?

You have to create the zip, from the main module. We have achieved it from other submodules but it is necessary to create it from the main one.

Thank you so much

Comment: Build order in Maven follows the dependencies. Create a sub module with the module1..3 as dependencies and there create the assembly. Parent modules in Maven are only for holding sub modules together and defining common properties to the build process.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Maven 2? It was end of life in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a `post-package` phase but unfortunately no such phase exists (see [introduction to the build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html))

A couple of options to get the behavior you desire

1. Create another subproject (eg `module4`) which lists `module1`, `module2` and `module3` as `<dependencies>` (so that `module4` is guaranteed to run last in the reactor). Then move the `maven-assembly-plugin` logic to `module4`
2. Change the "phase" from `<phase>package</phase>` to `<phase>verify</phase>` (this feels like a hack to me since you shouldn't be creating assemblies in the verify phase)

Comment: Yes, this was the configuration I made. The problem is that we have a pipeline that must collect the zip generated from the main module.
And the pipeline cannot be modified.

Thank you so much

Comment: That seems like a silly requirement. But I'm sure you could configure the assembly plugin (in module4) to write the zip to the "main" folder. A bit of a hack

Comment: Indeed, from another module we have been able to generate the zip file and take it to the main module. But it's not worth it. We continue investigating possibilities.
Thank you so much

Comment: The "package" phase of the main module runs before the "package" phase of the submodules. So you'll either need to use another phase, or do it in a submodule

Answer (score 0):

Create another module that will create such packaging.
The main reason of the parent module is to organize its children, share configuraton etc not to "build and package children into some other artifact"

Comment: Yes, this was the configuration I made. The problem is that we have a pipeline that must collect the zip generated from the main module.
And the pipeline cannot be modified

Thank you so much